# How to continue request post after internet disconnected

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
with open("student.csv", "r") as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r ]
    groups = {}

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['name'])):
        items = []
        for i in g:
        #data processing
        try:
           post_api = requests.post(ENDPOINT_URL, json=groups, headers=headers)
        except requests.ConnectionError:
              print("Something went wrong")
        finally:
              print("resume post request")
```

Currently, my code won't be able to resume the post request when the internet connection is disconnected. It's not working if I use the try and exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you can resume like you want without server side implementation as well but you can resume from the client.  Here is a simple blocking example but you may want to throw it in a thread.

```
import csv
import socket
from time import sleep

import requests


def is_internet_on():
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(3)
        socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect(('1.1.1.1', '8080'))
        return True
    except:
        return False


def do_call_later(url, headers, body):
    while not is_internet_on():
        sleep(5)
    requests.post(url, headers=headers, body=body)


with open("student.csv", "r") as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r]
    groups = {}

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['name'])):
        items = []
        for i in g:
            # data processing
            pass
        try:
            timeout_arg = (
                # first tuple value is the connection timeout,
                # how long to wait before initial connection is established
                1.0,
                # second tuple value is the read timeout, this is how long
                # the client will wait after the initial connection
                # before dropping the connection because no response was sent
                1.0
            )
            post_api = requests.post(ENDPOINT_URL, json=groups, headers=headers, timeout=timeout_arg)
        except requests.ConnectionError:
            do_call_later(ENDPOINT_URL, headers, groups)
        finally:
            print("resume post request")
```

Edit: docs for the timeout call: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py#L34

Comment: Same with my code. The script is running after the internet is disconnected but it didn't return any error or successful. It just like pausing.

Comment: @kino.jom, update the code your code is just missing a specified connection timeout and read timeout.  See `timeout=timeout_arg` in the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if it can work like this.

The idea for resumable request is to send data in chunks and then assemble as the backend.Therefore if a request fails in between, it can resume later by sending other chunks.
Also the backend should be able to accept chunks and assemble them

Take a look at a python library [resumable](https://pypi.org/project/resumable/)